# how" set jump" and "long jump" differs from "try catch" in stack pointer modification?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, stack

There was a discussion on the difference between how the setjmp  and longjmp    and "try catch" handles the allocation on stack.

1. After the jump routines finishes do they restore stack pointer
2. Do they have to be in the same context or same function block for this to   happen
3. When I have a function call in the "try" section of "try catch" After the   call where  stack pointer will be returned  if  we got into the catch section   by some exception.

Comment: With the POSIX jmp feature - typically sp is just saved/restored but this is not guaranteed.   The only thing you get for sure is that the call environment (ie. data on the stack) is the same after the jump as it was during the set.  Registers and signal mask state is implementation-dependent.   set/longjmp code is notoriously hard to write portably.  There is no requirement to have the set/jump in the same lexical context.  With regard to try/catch - are you talking about the C++ try/catch, or something else?

Comment: There's no "try/catch" in C. It's hard to compare something real (setjmp) with something that is not.

Comment: I will  edit the tag to include c++ also. The question as such is language agnostic I believe.

Comment: Not all languages implement try/catch in the same way!  And set/longjmp is most definitely a C library feature.

Comment: @BadZen you write _typically sp is just saved/restored but this is not guaranteed_. How could setjmp/longjmp work if the stack pointer is not restored ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz - It would be perfectly valid to copy or move the stack address after a `longjmp`, as I read the specification.   It doesn't talk about sepecific machine features, but rather about the execution /environment/. Typically, yes, this is done by simple save/restore of sp, but I don't think anything in POSIX even assumes a stack-based architecture! (Or that there is a single stack, etc...)

Comment: The C standard does not explain how setjmp / longjmp is implemented. There are different implementations. Including ones that use much of the underlying data structures of "zero-cost `try` / `catch`" to restore registers ( http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/man/libunwind-setjmp(3).html , sometimes also called "turbo-setjmp").